# Android App crashes when reopening

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

My Android app crashes when I reopen the app.

Example:

1. Open the app to Main Activity.
2. Navigate to a different Activity (MyEventsActivity).
3. Open a new fragment within the Activity (MyEventsCreator).
4. While the new fragment is active, I exit the App by clicking HOME screen of the phone.
5. Then let the App to run in the background for a few hours.
6. Finally, when I reopen the App, it will start with a white screen and then crashes.

I tried to solve this issue for weeks. Read about every forum to find a solution. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

This is the error log,

```
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.events/com.events.MyEventsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
7-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3337)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:143)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.events.ui.MyEventsCreator.onCreateView(MyEventsCreator.java:60)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:1911)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:809)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:786)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:333)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5343)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1124)
07-28 07:11:50.432: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3324)
```

Thank you so much.

This is the MyEventsCreator.java. But the app crashes on every fragment whenever the app is reopened.
I will post another error log. That case it crashes on a different place.

public class MyEventsCreator extends CustomFragment
{

```
private Player currentPlayer;
private List<MyEvent> creatorEvents = new ArrayList<MyEvent>(); 
private ListView eventListView;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private SharedDataSet sharedData;   
private EventFunctions eventFunctions = new EventFunctions();

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myevents, null);

    eventListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_MyEvents);            

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    sharedData = (SharedDataSet) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    currentPlayer = sharedData.getLoggedInPlayer(); // get the currently logged in player   

    if (currentPlayer != null)
    {               
        creatorEvents = eventFunctions.getEventsListFromUId(currentPlayer.getID(), EventFunctions.ParticipantTypes.Creator);

        eventListView.setAdapter(new EventsAdapter());
        eventListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View convertView, int position,
                    long arg3)
            {

                transferSync trasnferTask = new transferSync();
                trasnferTask.execute(position + "");    

            }       
        });

    } else 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);      
        getActivity().finish();
    }       


    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the code of `MyEventsCreator.java`. The error you get happens at line 60 of that code, so indicate which is line 60 also.

Comment: I will post the code in a few hours

Comment: Hello Salem, here I have posted the code. thanks

Comment: And line 60 is which??

Comment: Line 60 is     currentPlayer = sharedData.getLoggedInPlayer(); // get the currently logged in player                     thanks